# Symfony 2 - included form in all views and handled by one controller

Tags: php, forms, symfony, controller, embed

I am using Symfony 2 and having a little issue with an embeded form.

**The situation :**

MyBundle/Resources/views/Portions/footer.html.twig view which is included in the MyBundle/Resources/views/layout, and of course the layout.twig.html is extended by all the bundle views. Whish means that footer.html.twig is displayed in all the pages.

**The question / problem :**

I want to embed a newsletter form (one input) in the footer.html.twig, that would be handled by one controller (validate data, database insert, and email send), and afterward, returning to the same page.

What is the optimized solution to handle this ?

Thank you.

Comment: "the best optimized solution" is primarily opinion based....

Comment: Will that result a lack of understanding ? Anyway... I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an easy way of doing this (not the best way)

Is to simple define a service, as a twig global, that way you can have your form available, to twig, all the time.

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    ...
    globals:
        myGlobaService: "@acme.newsletter_service"
```

Another simple way of doing this, is to just use the twig render tag, to include the entire controller action, wich renders the template.

```
{{ render(controller('AcmeNewsLetterBundle:Default:renderNewsletterForm', {})) }}
```